# Swift 3: iMessage Extension detect User tap on Message and Detect Manual Slide

Tags: ios, swift, imessage-extension

1. How i can detect user taps on Message in conversation?
2. If MessageViewController Controller is compact and user slides up how i can detect that?

I tried these delegates but its not working properly

```
override func didSelect(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
   print("DID SELCT")
}
override func willSelect(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
    print("WILL SELCT")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Q1. How i can detect user taps on Message in conversation?

A1. In iOS 11 and later you can use live layouts for your messages (see the class `MSMessageLiveLayout` (`@available(iOS 11.0, *)`).  When doing so, you can add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` instance to the view that is presented in the conversation transcript when your `MSMessagesAppViewController` instance's `presentationStyle` is `.transcript` (`@available(iOS 11.0, *)`).

See the video `What's New in iMessage Apps` from `WWDC 2017 - Session 234 - iOS` ( https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/234/?time=1726 ).  At about 29 minutes into the presentation, you will find the tap gesture recognizer discussion.  See earlier in the video for how to detect the `.transcript` presentation style in the `willBecomeActive(with:)` method of your `MSMessagesAppViewController` subclass, and present the appropriate child view controller.

Q2. If MessageViewController Controller is compact and user slides up how i can detect that?

A2. Override `willTransition(to:)` in your `MSMessagesAppViewController` subclass like so:

```
override func willTransition(to newPresentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle) {
    super.willTransition(to: newPresentationStyle)  // don't forget to call super

    // note that MSMessagesAppViewController's `presentationStyle` property holds the presentation style BEFORE the transition
    print("will transition() from \(presentationStyle.rawValue) to \(newPresentationStyle.rawValue) [0 = .compact, 1 = .expanded, 2 = .transcript]")

    if (presentationStyle == .compact && newPresentationStyle == .expanded) {
        // handle transition from .compact to .expanded here

    }
}
```